# Removing horizontal scrollbar from list control in report mode

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have a list control in report mode and I'd like to remove the horizontal scrollbar from the list control and if the lines are too long, I'd have the remainder simply being truncated.

It's should be like using `LVS_NOSCROLL` but only for the horizontal scrollbar.

`LVS_NOSCROLL` does almost what I want but:

- it removes also the vertical scrollbar
- the list control's header is no longer displayed

**Or in pictures:**

I want this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

All information I've found is about the `LVS_NOSCROLL` style being not compatible with the `LVS_LIST` or `LVS_REPORT`, referencing a "Knowledge Base Article Q137520" which I couln'd find anywhere.

Does anybody have an idea ?

Comment: `SetWindowLong(hList,GWL_STYLE,GetWindowLong(hList,GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_HSCROLL);`

Comment: @milevyo That's not enough. You have to do that in response to `WM_NCCALCSIZE` as demonstrated in the dupe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i was about to give a full answer ,when it pops up that this question is closed and do not accept any more answer. so i stoped there, but my idea was not to intercept WM_NCCALCSIZE, but to intercept WM_STYLECHANGED and WM_STYLECHANGING instead

Comment: Add that answer to the dupe if you wish. You'd need to use `WM_STYLECHANGING` rather than `WM_STYLECHANGED`. Don't know if it would work, but it should.

Comment: @milevyo FWIW though, I don't think `WM_STYLECHANGING` fires when the control changes this style. I can't see past `WM_NCCALCSIZE`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it does :)

Comment: @milevyo Not for me. Anyway this is a clear dupe, and if you want to add an answer, you can do so over there.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK, i will try to.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, i am surprised , you are right. it fires the style changed, but whatever you do, it won't remove the scroll bar;

Comment: @milevyo That's not what I see. FWIW, **changed** is no good, you need **changing**. And you need to check the value of `wParam` to know whether it is the style of the extended style that is changing. When you do that, then I see lots of notifications for extended style changing, but not so much for the style.

Comment: @milevyo Changed is no use here because it's notifying you after the event. Only changing allows you to influence the change.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan again, you are right, it doesn't .